# How to fix warning "interaction added to non-interactive element no-invalid-interactive"

Tags: ember.js, accessibility, ember.js-3

I just upgraded my Ember addon from version 3.0 to version 3.8, and I get this warning now:

> Interaction added to non-interactive element no-invalid-interactive

An example of this is something like:

```
<div class="some-class" onclick={{action "selectDate" "today"}}>
    <div> more content </div>
</div>
```

When you click the action, it should take you to a new route.

What are my options to fix it the right way, so that it is accessible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution here depends on what the action should do.

**Refactoring an action that triggers a transition**

Since this action takes the user to a new route, it should be a link element, `<a>` and not a button. This gives assistive technology/screen reader users a clue that interacting will take them somewhere new in the app.

This can be refactored to a link-to in Ember, which will wrap the content in `<a>`:

```html
{{#link-to someRoute}}
    <div> more content </div>
{{/link-to}}
```

`someRoute` could be a computed property if it needs to be informed by multiple pieces of data. Otherwise, it could be a string.

**Refactoring an interaction that keeps you on the same page**

In cases where the action does not take you to a different page, it may be appropriate to use a `<button>`. An example of this would be a button that expands a collapsible container or toggles a setting. However, the [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) tells us that you can't put divs inside of buttons. You can use [Phrasing Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) that is non-[interactive](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2), such as `<span>`.

```html
<button class="some-class" onclick={{action "toggleSomething"}}>
    <span> more content </span>
</button>
```

**Learn More**

To catch more accessibility problems in an app, try out [ember-a11y-testing](https://github.com/ember-a11y/ember-a11y-testing) which audits your app for problems and gives you a report of how to fix them.

---

This question was answered as part of "May I Ask a Question" Season 2 Episode 3. If you would like to see us discuss this answer in full you can check out the video here: https://youtu.be/nQsG1zjl8H4

Comment: In the second code snippet, is that div supposed to be a button?

Comment: @steveax thanks, I have updated the example there now 